# How iterate in a dataframe of pandas with date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with my dataframe, especially in a column where I have date format that looks like this

```
01/03/2021, 21:46:19
```

I have used the following syntaxes to put it in this format

```
def change_format(day):
  if day != 'nan':  
    format_1 = datetime.strptime(day, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z  %Y")
    new_format = format_1.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S')
    return new_format

concatenar['Dia_siniestro']=concatenar['Dia_siniestro'].apply(change_format)
```

and now I want a dataframe with only the rows where the month is '02' (february) but I have rows with the months january, april....

I was thinking that by iterating I can do it but I don't know if this way is the best or if there is another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can use [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

```
concatenar['Dia_siniestro']=pd.to_datetime(concatenar['Dia_siniestro'],format='%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
```

Finally use boolean masking:

```
resultdf=concatenar[concatenar['Dia_siniestro'].dt.month==2]
```

Now if you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output